# jpa attribute convertor for encryption

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

We are using JPA attribute convertor for encrypting entity attributes as per the below example .

https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/

While doing the encryption , I want to use one of the entity attribute as the key for encryption .
But I am not sure if I can access the entity attributes from within the AttributeConvertor .

Is it possible to pass any other properties of the entity to the AttributeConvertor ?

The other option is to use @PrePersist and @PostLoad annotations. But since we are using JPA 2.0 , I would prefer to use convertor annotation if it can help in this scenario.

---

I am doing the encyrption of data using the sample convertor in the below link

https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-use-jpa-type-converter-to/

In this example , there is a key used for encryption and decryption .

If we are planning to use a hard coded key for encryption/decryption then the solution would work perfect.

I would like to derive the key based on the properties of the entity. Hence even if a hacker identifies the encryption logic, it would be difficult to identify the key .

Hope I have clarified the intent.

Comment: `@PrePersist` and `@PostLoad` seems orthodox. I understand 'encryption' is at amateur level? I can't give recommendation for high level encryption

Comment: I have elaborated my question

Comment: If you want to use an attribute from the entity then PrePersist and PostLoad would be the better solution. You can't access entity state in attribute converter.

Comment: Thanks  Simon Martinelli for the clarification